# VS2010 msbuild msdeploy deployment package not performing web.config transformations

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, msdeploy

i've got two different web projects that i'm deploying via msdeploy and tfs. one performs a transformation on the web.config and the other does not.

the only difference between these projects is really the fact that the one that isn't working was converted from a v2 framework and vs 2008 app to v4 framework and vs 2010. i can't think of anything else that is different.

but when i click 'build deployment package' and look at the contents of the .zip file (for both projects) the one works and does contain the transformed web.config, and the other ('older') project does not. it only shows the web.debug.config and web.release.config.

please - any ideas?!

Answer (score 1):

Examine the project files as XML.  See of the upgraded one happens to have the TransformWebConfigEnabled property set to false.  If not, diff the two project files files and pay attention to how the files involved in the Web.config transformation are declared in the project.

Comment: thanks spiderm9 for the suggestion, however after doing this, it's still acting the same. the projects i'm comparing are different web apps, so a diff can't be performed, only a manual comparison. also transformwebconfigenabled is not present as a node at all.